# index.tsx in package react-router has 152 problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

Everything seems to work fine, I just see those errors. Is this normal? How can i fix this.
My react application is written in Javascript, not in Typescript, but I do not think that this should matter, should it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just restarted Visual Studio Code and the errors disappeared.

For context, I had Visual Studio running for some days now, so I can see how this could lead to some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a package manager like npm/yarn/pnpm for installing react-router? Looking at that pathname it kinda looks like you're not and you should be.

If you're trying to import the index.tsx file directly in your JavaScript it won't work, you'll need the transpiled version which would be available automatically by installing it through a package manager (something like `npm install react-router`). The plain js files would then be available under `node_modules/react-router` in the root directory of your project.

To import it somewhere in a React project you could then use:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router'
```

(no need for the full path name including node_modules - more info on npm install here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install)

Comment: Yes i use a package manager, npm.
And yes i imported it like show above: eg. import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";